# jQuery if inside a function undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I have this simple code that shows an image and a word and you have to complete the field. If you write the word correctly, a congrats popup comes up.

I was able to figure out how to randomize items in an `array` to display a random image.
Now I want to check on each `keyup` if it matches that random word.

It seems there's something wrong with my `IF` statement because if I remove it, popup works perfectly.

Error:

> uncaught typeerror undefined is not a function

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>AutistApp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="container">

        <div class="eval">CORRECTO</div>
        <div class="siguiente"><a href=".">&iexcl;OTRA VEZ!</a></div>

        <div class="dibujo"><img id="dibujito" src="img/apple.png" /></div>
        <div class="palabra">MANZANA</div>
        <div class="respuesta"><input type="text" id="resp" name="resp" value=""/>
        </div>
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

/***** RANDOM VALUES *****/
var messages = ["manzana", "pera", "banana"],
    message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];

$('.palabra').text(message);
$('#dibujito').attr('src','img/'+message+'.png');

/***** KEYDOWN CHECK *****/
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#resp').keyup(function(){
        if ($("#resp").value() == message) {
            $('.eval').slideDown();
            $('.eval').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $('.siguiente').delay(3000).slideDown();
        }
    });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a `value()` method, it's `val()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use **[.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** instead of `.value()` to get the value of `input` element, so you can do:

```
if ($("#resp").val() == message) {
```

instead of:

```
if ($("#resp").value() == message) {
```

You also need to wrap all of your code inside DOM ready handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var messages = ["manzana", "pera", "banana"],
        message = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];

    $('.palabra').text(message);
    $('#dibujito').attr('src', 'img/' + message + '.png');

    $('#resp').keyup(function () {
        if ($("#resp").val() == message) {
            $('.eval').slideDown();
            $('.eval').delay(3000).fadeOut();
            $('.siguiente').delay(3000).slideDown();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Folks you need to use

```
 $("#resp").val()
```

in if condition.